# Filter within Mongo embedded document by range

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```json
{
    '_id': '...',
    'friends': {
        'id1': {'name': 'john', 'dateAdded': ISODate(...)},
        'id2': {'name': 'joe', 'dateAdded': ISODate(...)},
         ...
    }
}
```

I will like to filter the collection by `friends` attribute `dateAdded` **without** changing the collection model.

Is there an operator that makes filtering inside an embedded document dictionary possible?

Where the query will look like this:

```py
self.collection.find({
    'friends.$operator.dateAdded': {
        '$gte': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1),
        '$lte': datetime.datetime(2001, 9, 1)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no operator to perform what you are asking. In (very) simplistic terms, think of MongoDB as key/value store; you need to know the key in order to determine the value.

If you have the option to, refactor your schema so that `friends` is an array and lose the `id`s. In general it is poor design to have arbitrary-named keys such as `id[n]`.

Comment: Still, if I use an array, how can I filter the array at the same time that doing a find() ?

Comment: Use `elemMatch` or an aggretion pipeline.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you !